# How can I not show the phone screen all the time when making a call?

Tags: javascript, android

I have written an application which include a service running in the background, and a GUI that includes (amongst other things) the ability to make a call to a predefined number.
Now- when the user presses the button to make the call- the call is made OK- and the screen changes to the phone's GUI. I'd rather the app stays in view and the phone isn't shown at all really- but I can live with it briefly showing. However, to return to the application, the user must manually click the "back button£" on the phone. I want this to happen immediately the call is ringing if at all possible.
I have tried using the PhoneStateListener- which I am already using for something else (in the service part of the app)- but can't seem to detect the call being made, and then show the main screen again.

Suggestions would be much appreciated!
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/

Comment: Hi thanks for the link.I'm already using the@Override     
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) to detect incoming SMS messages- can I include the code for detecting  an outgoping call in there as well(apologies in advance for my ignorance!)?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to create a new broadcastreciver class and add this intent to it.

Comment: Hi can you have 2 broadcastreciver classes overriden- both implementing Onreceive? (I new to all this- sorry)

Comment: Yes, you can have as many BroadCastReceivers as you like. Just create different class for them, and different receivers in manifest associated to specific class receiver.

Comment: I have never implement this OUTGOING_CALL intent, otherwise I would have provided the code as an answer. But if you check that tutorial and have a little search about this Intent you will sure find a solution :)

Comment: Ok- I think I need to start simple here (for me- not anyone else!).The application makes the call OK, frm a button on the screen using:    _startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phoneCallUri))); where phoneCallUri=  = "tel:012345678";_ However,when the call is made, a message appears stating the app has stopped working. Either this, or if the call is quick, the screen returns t the app, but it is frozen annd then the message appears saying the app has stopped working. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: did you add the call permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">

Comment: Yes- that hadn't got passed me. the call is made OK- it just crasshes the app. The app, as I said consists of a GUI screen and a service. The service runs all the time (obviously).

Comment: What's the error saying? You can see it in LogCat

Comment: Activity.onPause()

Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0

threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40de41f8)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: 10-19 14:25:23.504: E/AndroidRuntime(21852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.delma.trakcarguardservice.TrakcarGuardService: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.delma.trakcarguardservice.TrakcarGuardService cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Currently- I'm only using the Broadcast receiver to monitor for incoming SMS messages

Comment: I've just commented all the code out of my private class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver- procedure but still get the same error.

Comment: Edit your question, and add your Manifest XML and your class which listen for outgoing call (BroadCastReceiver). So I can see in your code what's wrong.

Comment: Struggling to get the Manifest to appear in the question!

Comment: It saves Ok- but doesn't show up- just as blank space

Comment: Strange :S ... mark all your code and when it is selected, hold down your ctrl key and press K.

Comment: Can't get the Manifest to show!!!

Comment: OK- so there is no class extending the BroadcastReceiver anymore- I commented that out.The call is made so I can assume (if this is logical) the poermissions are correct. The only thinkg that's left is the fact I'm running a service in the backgroungd in the same application and this is causing the issue.

Comment: Mate, it's really hard to help you when I don't know your exact problem. Try to post your error here somehow!

Comment: I really appreciate your help (despite my problems posting it). The (relevant) permissions set in the manifest are: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/> and

Comment: (revalent) intents are: <receiver android:name="com.delma.trakcarguardservice.TrakcarGuardService">   <intent-filter>                              
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>                         
        </intent-filter>                  
    </receiver>

Comment: Code co form:
private OnClickListener callAlert = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){
try{
String phoneCallUri = "tel:077---------";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phoneCallUri)));
finish(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

Comment: Code from PhoneStateListener now commented out for debugging this error- so not relevant

Comment: Where is the error? You said that your Service (background task) is occurring an error, find that error in Logcat.

Comment: Activity.onPause()
10-22 14:07:22.721: D/Activity(2849): 
Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
10-22 14:08:05.673: W/dalvikvm(2849): 
threadid=1: 
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dd91f8)
10-22 14:08:05.683: 
E/AndroidRuntime(2849): 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Although there are Try- catches around everthing! It only crashes when the call is made.

Comment: I am using public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
as well in PhoneStateListener- but I can't see how this will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you need such fine grained control over the call experience, why don't you just use Twilio Client?

http://www.twilio.com/client/mobile

This lets you control the entire voice experience.

Comment: ...because I don't want to rely on having a data connection available to make a call, amongst other things.